# Drop down multi select check box

Tags: jquery

How to bind drop down list along with checkbox values and multi select options using Jquery. I am trying to filter the Subcategory while selecting Category but values are not binding in the Subcategory dropdown . Please help me to fix this issue.
 here is my code as below :

```
$.each(response.SubCategory, function (i, item) {
     //items += "<option value=\"" 
             + item.Value + "\"><input type=\"checkbox\">"
             + item.Text + "</option>"; items += "<option value=\""
             + item.Value + "\"><input type=\"checkbox\"></option>"; 
     //$("#SubCategory1").append("<li><a rel=external href=Category.html?ID=" 
             + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</li>"); 
     alert($("#SubCategory"));
});
$("#SubCategory").html(items);
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: $.each(response.SubCategory, function (i, item) {
                            //items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\"><input type=\"checkbox\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                            items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\"><input type=\"checkbox\"></option>";
                            //$("#SubCategory1").append("<li><a rel=external href=Category.html?ID=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</li>");
                            alert($("#SubCategory"));
                        });
                        $("#SubCategory").html(items);

Answer (score 0):

.change( handler )

Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

For help please read the following as it is given very clearly and will help you a lot:-

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: But mine is different scenario because I am trying to bind filtered  values using Jquery Json object. Values are coming correctly but not able to bind to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 //In case You want to reset SubCategory dropdown 
 $('#SubCategory').find('option').remove().end();
 $.each(response.SubCategory, function (i, item) {
    $("#SubCategory").append("<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\"><input type=\"checkbox\"> </option>");
 });
```

Comment: I am using like this and trying to bind. but really problem is not here getting values using Json object and while binding to the controllere it's not binding.$("#Category").change(function () {

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for that, so i can get a clear view of your problem  [link] http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: var items = "";
                        $.each(response.SubCategory, function (i, item) {
                            //items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\"><input type=\"checkbox\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                            items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\"><input type=\"checkbox\"></option>";
                            //$("#SubCategory1").append("<li><a rel=external href=Category.html?ID=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</li>");
                        });
                        $("#SubCategory").html(items);

Comment: @bujjibabu please check my edited answer .If it is working for you.

Comment: Thanks Vipul for your help but it's not working binding the values but not with check box.

Comment: Actually you can't do that.For this either you have to create your own plugin or you can use so many that are available online.Check this link http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html  also you can go through this  fiddle also http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/w7aakdbb/

Comment: This stuff all are working fine for me but problem is cascading drop down list. If I select some values in the Category field that time Subcategory will call the Jason object and filter the values of SubCategory fields that time it's not binding the values to the Subcategory dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code and get multi-select drop down with checkbox using jquery / ajax. additionally you should add jquery to work on this program.if you have any question regarding this please comment.

```js
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
 
 <script>
 var expanded = false;
 function showCheckBoxes(){
 
 var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
 if(!expanded){
  checkboxes.style.display = "block";
  expanded = true;
 
 }else{
  checkboxes.style.display = "none";
  expanded = false;
 
 }
 
 }
 
</script>
 
 
 <script>

            function getcategory() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       
       var node = document.createElement('div');        
       node.innerHTML = '<label id="'+ data[i].id +'"><input type="checkbox"  id="'+ data[i].id +'"/>'+data[i].id +'</label>';       
          document.getElementById('checkboxes').appendChild(node);

                        }

                    },
                    error: function (msg) {

                        alert("error" + msg);
                    }

                });
            }

        </script>
```

```css
<style>
.multiselect {
 width: 200px;
}
.selectBox {
 position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 
}
#checkboxes{
 display: none;
 border: 1px #dadada solid;
}
#checkboxes label {
 display: block;
}
#checkboxes label:hover {
 background-color : #1e90ff;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="getcategory();">

<div>
 <div class="multiselect">
  <div class="selectbox" onclick="showCheckBoxes()">
   <select>
    <option>Select option</option>
   </select>
   
   <div class="overSelect"></div>
 
  </div> 
  
  <div id="checkboxes">
   
  </div>
  
 </div>

</div>

</body>
```